# Convert UTxO to hex encoded bytes string

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-serialization-lib, nami-wallet, cardano-address

Hello I want to convert a normal UTxO transaction hash to an encoded bytes string. How do I do this? Help would be appreciated!

something like

`550665309dee7e2f64d13f999297f001763f65fe50bb05524afc0990c7dce0c3`

to

`828258205537396d59c1b0546bb9cec5cb6b930238af2d8998d24ca1d47e89a3dd400a8701825839016af9a0d2c9b5bce8999bc6430eb48f424399b73f0ecc143f40e8cac89b130cc3198a8594862fe25df331cb79447304dcd49712c86834fdf1821a00150bd0a1581cb0df0ee7dbb96b18b682a1091514f250eb0ec1122e6c4bf3b4d45123a14b436f6e766963743033363701`

Comment: I don't understand. The first string you provides is hex encoded.

Comment: Would be helpful to also share why you trying to do this and what is your final goal.
This way someone can provide different types of solution related to your question

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to convert from base 16 to base 10 which is how a bytestring is stored on the blockchain.  You can take a look at my Deploy.hs code which does this conversion.

https://github.com/lley154/cardano-lottery/blob/main/src/Deploy.hs

Eg.

```
txIdBS :: B.ByteString
txIdBS = "aa604b873b89ea9e0f430e6c7b9af5d2bf426d88856eff97927e8469a196cdbd"

let some_val = $ decodeHex txIdBS 

-- | Decode from hex base 16 to a base 10 bytestring is needed because
--   that is how it is stored in the ledger onchain
where

decodeHex :: B.ByteString -> PlutusPrelude.BuiltinByteString
decodeHex hexBS =    
         case getTx of
            Right decHex -> do
                --putStrLn $ "Tx name: " ++ show t
                PlutusPrelude.toBuiltin(decHex)  
            Left _ -> do
                --putStrLn $ "No Token name: " ++ show e
                PlutusPrelude.emptyByteString 
                
        where        
            getTx :: Either String B.ByteString = B16.decode hexBS
```